# How to get proficient?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm currently a 1st year undergrad and I feel like my mathematical ability is very poor.

I want to get better at a lot of different areas so I can feel very comfortable with mathematics.

I see people on here and other places who know a great deal and can solve most university+ type questions I would like to get like this.

Obviously this comes from a lot of experience but is there anything I can do to try and get myself into that category I wish I was in.

Answer (score 2):

Fall in love with mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Study. A lot.

Be curious and, if possible, try to go beyond what is strictly necessary to pass your exams or get your grades. And never believe anything to be true unless you see a proof of it and manage to understand it. In particular, try to prove all those statements you will find in your textbooks which are allegedly labelled as "trivially true", "straightforward to prove" or "easy to check".

Talk with your colleagues a lot and listen to the most expert, smart and good among them. Ask them questions, manifest them your doubts, what is unclear, fuzzy or indigestible to you: you want to learn from those who seem to understand things better than what you can do.

And, once more, study. A lot.